# DWARF line info appears to be corrupt - the section is too small

Tags: c, warnings, valgrind

Hi I am running `Valgrind` on my code which uses a third party library.
I got the following warning: can anyone help how to solve it ?

```
--18997-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info

--18997-- When reading debug info from --- Third party library (/lib/lib----)

--18997-- DWARF line info appears to be corrupt - the section is too small

--18997-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info

--18997-- When reading debug info from --- Third party library (/lib/lib----)

--18997-- read_filename_table: .debug_line is missing?
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Please consider adding relevant code snippets

Comment: i do not know which code snippet to add. I am linking a library which has some 300 files.